# Webscraping an entire website pandas word cloud

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, word-cloud

I'm attempting to create a wordcloud based off the **scraped** text from a specific website. The issue I'm having is with the webscraping portion of this. I've attempted two different ways, and both attempts I get stuck on how to proceed further.

First method:
**Scrape** the data for each specific tag into its own data frame

```
main_content= soup.find("div", attrs= {"class" : "col-md-4"})
main_content2= soup.find("article", attrs= {"class" : "col-lg-7 mid_info"})
comp_service= soup.find("div", attrs= {"class" : "col-md-6 col-lg-4"})
```

Here I'm stuck on how to add the three dataframes together in order to create the word cloud. This works fine if I use only one of the DF's and add it into 'lists' but I'm unsure how to add the other two into a single DF to then run the rest of the code. The following is the rest of the code for the word cloud potion:

```
str = ""
for list in lists:
    info= list.text
    str+=info

mask = np.array(Image.open("Desktop/big.png"))
color= ImageColorGenerator(mask)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1200, height=1000, 
                      max_words=400,mask=mask, 
                      stopwords=STOPWORDS, 
                      background_color="white",
                      random_state=42).generate(str)

plt.imshow(wordcloud.recolor(color_func=color),interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Attempt 2
I found a peice of code that will extract all of the data from specific tags and put it into text

```
i = 0
for lists in soup.find_all(['article','div']):
    print (lists.text)
```

However, when I attempt to run the rest of the code,

```
mask = np.array(Image.open("Desktop/big.png"))
color= ImageColorGenerator(mask)

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1200, height=1000, 
                      max_words=400,mask=mask, 
                      stopwords=STOPWORDS, 
                      background_color="white",
                      random_state=42).generate(str)

plt.imshow(wordcloud.recolor(color_func=color),interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I get 'ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0.' after running the wordcloud DF code.

I'm essentially just trying to pull all of the data from a website, store that information into a text file, then transform that data into a word cloud.

Please let me know any suggestions or clarifications I can provide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me

```
lists = soup.find_all(['article','div'])
str = ""
for list in lists:
    info= list.text
    str+=info
```